# How to use event binding inside class in tkinter, Dealing with event and self

Tags: tkinter, self, event-binding

When i was trying to event bind inside my class, binding event creates argument error. Codes are written below-

```
class Login_App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_lgin = ttk.Button(self, text="Login")
        self.btn_lgin.grid()
        self.btn_lgin.bind('<Return>', lambda: Login(self=self))

    def Login(self):
        '''I need "Self" in some codes, cant remove it'''
        print("Clicked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Login_App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only do a minor change:

When calling a function with a parameter `self` inside a `class` self is not an actual parameter so you don't need to pass it as one. 
What you should do is:

```
self.btn_lgin.bind('<Return>', lambda x: self.Login())
```

Be aware that when you change this you should also change:
`lambda:` to `lambda x:` because `lambda:` gets one positional argument when you've passed zero, leading to `TypeError`